# Unable to install openchrome driver

Tags: linux-mint, repository

After install needed dependencies

> svn checkout http://svn.openchrome.org/svn/trunk openchrom svn:
>   E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>   'http://svn.openchrome.org/svn/trunk' svn: E670002: Unknown name or
>   service

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that repository is no longer available. I had a quick Google and there looks to be a mirror on [Github](https://github.com/chutzimir/openchrome).

You should be able to use git or svn to get the required files from there.